# Driven Pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, resonance, non-linear-systems

If the point of suspension of a pendulum is driven periodically in the vertical direction , we can derive the equation of motion for the suspended mass to be of the form, $\ddot{\theta}(t) + (a-b\cos{t})\theta(t) = 0$, neglecting air resistance. $\theta(t)$ is a small angular displacement of the mass from the vertical axis. This equation is known as Mathieu equation and describes the dynamics of a parametric oscillator.

For a regular pendulum with length $l$ and mass $m$, subjected to a periodic driven displacement $A\cos(\omega \tau)$, the parameters $a$ and $b$ in the equation defined above are: $a = -g/l\omega^{2}$ and $b = -A/l$ with $t = \omega\tau$. $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Depending on the values of a and b, the oscillator could be operating in two regimes: 1) Stable regime, 2) Unstable regime. In the stable regime, any small perturbation decays with time, whereas, in the unstable regime, the perturbation grows with time. Thus it is often useful to identify these two regions of solution in the parameter space (a-b). Floquet theory could be applied to find the borderline between the unstable and stable regime.

In literature we find two different stability diagrams, one corresponding to harmonic resonance and the other corresponds to subharmonic resonance. What is the physical understanding behind these two distinct resonances?

Comment: Your description does not make sense to me - "the point of suspension ... driven in the vertical direction" Vertical force shouldn't impart any horizontal force - and so the pendulum should not swing at all.

Comment: Also considering the pendulum, it might help noting what a and b represent in terms of the physical parameters (e.g. length, gravity,etc.)

Comment: @docscience - it is definitely possible to impart momentum **to an _already swinging_ pendulum** by moving the support vertically. It is as though you are changing gravity - and the same mechanism that will cause a rotating bob on a string to speed up if you reel in the string. You can't _start_ the pendulum swinging, but you can _keep_ it moving.

Comment: @Floris I agree with what you say - that if the pendulum is already swinging you can pump energy into it by vertical motions. So I guess we just have to assume that - it isn't clear in the way the question is written. Also isn't there a variable missing in the equation? To account for the input of vertical force or displacement? I see only angle in the equation.

Comment: @docscience - yes, it seems to me that the $b\cos(t)$ term probably should be $b\cos(\omega t)$ to show the frequency of the forced oscillation.

Comment: @docscience-we do perturb the bob of the pendulum to observe any dynamics.

Comment: Could you show these two stability diagrams? or cite a source referencing them?